# Make height of absolutely postitioned div 100%

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, css-position

I have a absolutely positioned left side bar which contains the menu of website. But I am unable to make its height 100%.
I have tried many tweaks like making `bottom:0` etc.

**Update:** Enclosing it in a parent div having min-heigh:100% and position:relative solves the problem.

```
/* sidebar settings */
.sidebar {
    background-color: #404040;
    width: 90px;
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    top: 51px;
    /*bottom: 0;*/
    z-index: 1000;
    min-height: 100%;
    max-height: 400%;
    overflow: auto;
}

.sidebar-left {
    left: 0;
}

.sidebar ul li{
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 30px 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #535353;
}

.sidebar ul li a{
  color: #999999;
  float: left;
  font-family: 'gothamrounded-medium';
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 16px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border-left: 2px solid #404040;
  padding: 0 10%;
}

.sidebar ul li a:active, .sidebar ul li.active a, .sidebar ul li a:focus , .sidebar ul li a:hover{
  border-color: #e55d42;
  background-color: transparent;
  color: #fff;
}

.sidebar ul li a i{
  color: white !important;
  float: none;
  width: 23px;
  height: 26px;
  display: inline-table;
  display: table;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.f-profile, .f-courses, .f-videos, .f-pdf, .f-referral{
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 20px;
  background-position: center;
}
```

```html
<!-- sidebar -->
<div class="sidebar sidebar-left sidebar-animate sidebar-md-show" id="left-col">
  <ul class="nav navbar-stacked">
    <li class="active"><a href="#"><i class="f-profile" aria-hidden="true"></i>My profile</a></li>
    <li><a href="#about"><i class="f-courses" aria-hidden="true"></i>All Courses</a></li>
    <li><a href="#about"><i class="f-videos" aria-hidden="true"></i>Webinar Videos</a></li>
    <li><a href="#about"><i class="f-pdf" aria-hidden="true"></i>Webinar pdf</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact"><i class="f-referral" aria-hidden="true"></i>Referral Link</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<!-- sidebar -->
```

Comment: For a quick solution try to set BODY to postion relative. I see that you give BODY & HTML min-height 100%. Remove the max-height and min-height from .sidebar.

Comment: remove from body height 100% and add position relative but i dont know if it is correct way and if it suits your needs

Comment: change  position absolute to fixed in .sidebar like this .sidebar {position:fixed;}

Comment: @paragparmmar making .sidebar {position:fixed;} would not solve the problem. I want it to expand to 100% of height. position:fixed; cannot be a solution.

Comment: @nstungcom tried that. But it doesn't help.

Comment: @mamosek that too doesn't work.

Comment: Try remove height: 100%; from body,html and add min-height: 100%. It seems work for me when trying to edit live on your preview site.

Comment: @nstungcom Where to add min-height:100% ? It doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: @Irshad `html,body {min-height: 100%;}`

Comment: @Irshad It works mate, but in body, html css tag remove height, add position:relative and to your .sidebar class add height: 100%

Comment: add  your all tag in wrapper like this<body>
<div class="wrapper">
</div>
</body> and add this css .wrapper {
    min-height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this updated code:

```
html,body {
  min-height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.sidebar {
  background-color: #404040;
  width: 90px;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  z-index: 1000;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
  padding-top: 51px;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 728px)
.bg9 .workshop-text {
  padding-top: 9%;
  min-height: 450px;
  padding-bottom: 5%;
}
```

Remove min-height & max-height from .sidebar and add height: 100%; to .sidebar.

And here is a Screenshot how it looks like:

[image]

Comment: That doesn't make a difference.

Comment: Can you add height: 100%; to .sidebar and see if it work?

Comment: Yeah man your answer seems to work. Will have to make minor changes. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

for body :

```
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
```

and remove height:100%;

Comment: No trick seems to work. Did you get it what I want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

Use viewport units.

```
.sidebar {
    background-color: #404040;
    width: 90px;
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    top: 51px;
    /*bottom: 0;*/
    z-index: 1000;
    min-height: 100vh;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Rather then making the height relative to the parent, they make the height relative to your viewport.

[Documentation](https://web-design-weekly.com/2014/11/18/viewport-units-vw-vh-vmin-vmax/)

Comment: changing min-height to 100vh will make its height not less than the view port height. But what I want is to make it 100% of body height.

Answer (score 0):

@nstungcom is right, but you also need `bottom: 0` on your `.sidebar`. These are the modifications:

```
html,
body {
  min-height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
.sidebar {
  bottom: 0;
  /*position: fixed; /* maybe? */
}
```